# Are there any ready, official chronicles/stories for Dark Ages: Vampire?

Tags: world-of-darkness, published-adventures, vampire-the-dark-ages

My group, due to prolonged absence of one of players, has voted (yeah, we have votes) to play ***Dark Ages: Vampire*** (the revised edition of *Vampire: The Dark Ages*). As long as I like Vampires from WoD, I have absolutely no idea how to start a chronicle in historical period I'm not too familiar with, using book I only read once and for single-shot. And I have only four days to get ready (voting, with all it's obvious advantages, has some disadvantages as well, which include looong time to get anything done).

Therefore, I decided to use some ready story or chronicle. The problem is, **I found only one (*Dark Ages: Darkening Sky*)**. Its price is little too high for the book, which is only in 20% about what I'm interested in. If there is no other choice, I will buy it (I want to get other Dark Ages books anyway), but I would prefer to first see if there are any other source books.

My question is: **are there any official published chronicles or stories for Dark Ages: Vampire?**

Reminder: *Vampire: The Dark Ages* IS NOT *Dark Ages: Vampire*. I found quite a few for the first, and almost none for latter.

Comment: PS. Can someone add Dark Ages: Vampire tag?

Comment: So far, previous questions involving different editions of WW's historical game have been tagged with the VDA tag. I'll add that here, and if there's a need for a specific [tag:vampire-the-dark-ages-2e] we can add one.

Comment: Why did you decide to play such an old game, by the way?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy - Normally we play D&D5, but I have a small collection of various systems, including this game. We play with 5 players, but one of them had to return home for a month, and we did not want to make such long stop. I gave my players 10 things to choose from, and they have chosen Dark Ages: Vampire. Other choices were eg. Vampire: requiem and Masquarede, Werewolf:The Forsaken, Warhammer 2e, Dark Heresy 2e, Neuroshima and few others.

Comment: How did it work?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy I actually wrote my own story, basing on idea of my friend. I would gladly share, but it is in Polish anyway. It was fun actually, except all players died. But accusing Prince of treason is not exactly best idea, when you forgot or clues that led you to this conclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, and easily found

Go to the White Wolf Wikia, and check the [respective category](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Dark_Ages:_Vampire_books).

[The Ventrue Chronicle](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/The_Ventrue_Chronicle) I didn't read myself, but it seems so from the description that it's the thing you need, providing some plot for Dark Ages: Vampire.

You may [get it at DiveThruRPG](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/292/The-Ventrue-Chronicle?it=1) for 12$ as PDF -- you probably can't afford to wait for the delivery of the paper version if you only have 4 days!
The advantage is that this book actually has 3 stories, one for the Dark Ages, one for Victorian Age, and one for the Final Nights.

---

[Dark Ages: British Isles](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Dark_Ages:_British_Isles) is another book, which may be bought [here](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/1484/Dark-Ages-British-Isles?it=1&filters=0_0_1800_0_0). However, it has all 4 lines of supernaturals together, so I hope you know them all if you gonna play it. If you get it as PDF, don't forget to download *Dark Ages: British Isles Casualties* to see the cut content with more details.

Also if you want to learn the setting, you better buy other books from the series than a book on history, because the former will get you more useful information for actual play.

Comment: Do you own by any chance any of those books? A comment below Ventrue Chronicle is suggesting that it is just a scan - and hell no, I ain't paying 12$ for poor scan - but quick preview looks really good.

Comment: @PawełMach Ventrue Chronicles is your best bet for an out of the box chronicle

Comment: @PawełMach Read [this review](http://www.drivethrurpg.com/product_reviews_info.php?&reviews_id=68343&products_id=292&it=1) -- the file was updated long, long ago, it's text now that can be copied and pasted. But you may pay 23$ and get both the PDF and printed version. Use PDF for your upcoming game, and wait for the fine printed version to come. Good luck!

Answer (score -4):

The "[somewhere] by night" line include stories.

Thomas E. probably refers to Transylvania by Night.

Jerusalem by Night also includes a story ready to be played.

I have not read Iberia by Night, but I will put my money into saying it will also have a chronicle.

These three are from very old versions of Vampire Dark Ages, but you can easily use them.

Watch out for London by Night, since the setting is more in the victorian era, than in the Dark Ages.

On V20 Dark Ages, I don't think they have published a chronicle to play just yet. I just received their first expansion and I haven't had the opportunity to read it.

Comment: Sorry, but as I explicitly asked, I want books for Dark Ages: Vampire. All of those are for 1ed, Vampire: The Dark Ages. Not my downvote anyway, as this may be useful in case someone wanted plot only.

Comment: Oh! You are totally right. I screwed up. My fault and sorry for the miss information.